# Does Android Room wait for withTransaction block to finish before proceeding to next line

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

```
class MyViewModel(private val db: AppDatabase): ViewModel() {

    suspend fun insertAndRead(pages: List<Page>) {
        db.withTransaction {
            db.pageDao().insertAll(pages)    
        }
        val pagesInserted = db.pageDao().selectAll()
    }
}
```

I'm curious about the Room handles the `withTransaction` block.

Let's say with the code example above. Does Room wait for the `withTransaction` block to finish running, then go to then next line?

Or it simply runs the `withTransaction` block inside a coroutine, then starting the next line immediately without waiting for the `withTransaction` block to complete?

Comment: why you are not using coroutine .? 
use job it will execute next line on the job done.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withTransaction()` is a suspend function. Suspend functions generally wait by suspending, they are synchronous to their callers, they don't schedule asynchronous operations.

So the answer is: yes, it waits for the inner block to finish executing.